# delivery order of multiple files in SCP

Tags: linux, windows, scp

I want to push multiple files from node x to node y in such a way that they arrive at the destination in the lexical order of their timestamp extensions.

Examples:  a.20140508120001, a.20140508120002, etc.

A consumer application will be processing the files asycnronously as they arrive, but they must not be processed out of order.

Can a wildcard SCP push guarantee that the files arrive in order?

If it matters, the push will be made from a Linux to a Windows box.

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard is actually expanded by the shell, so technically, it depends on what shell you're using.

[POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03) specifies that filenames and pathnames are "sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale".

The [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) says that patterns are replaced with an "alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern".

Anyway, the bottom line is that a single wildcard like `a.*` should work fine. Keep in mind that if you specify multiple wildcards, they are expanded independently, which may result in the list as a whole not being sorted.